# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: One of the `NSLocation*UsageDescription` keys must be present in Info.plist to be able to use geolocation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to add background location tracking to my React-Native/Expo app (managed workflow SDK 42) but I keep getting an error, telling my I need to add a specific item to my Info.plist.

Below is my code for how I request for permissions in the app, as well as my Info.plist

//Code in my JS requesting background permissions

```
useEffect(()=> {

  let isActive = true;

  const requestBackgroundPermissions = async () =>{
    const {status} = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync()
    if(status === 'granted'){
      await Location.startLocationUpdateAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
      });
    }
  }

  async function getBackgroundLocationAsync() {
   let { status } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync()
     if(status !=='granted'){
       setErrorMsg('Permission to access background location was denied')
         return;
     }
     let backgroundLocation = await Location.getBackgroundPositionAsync({});
         setBackgroundLocation(backgroundLocation);
   }

   getBackgroundLocationAsync()

   return() =>{
     isActive=false
   }

 },
[],
)
```

//TaskManager, I don't know if I'm doing this part right

```
TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME,({data,error})=>{
    if(error){
      return;
    }
    if(data){
      const{locations} = data
    }
  })
```

//Info plist

```
"ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist":{
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription":"Allows App to use location services in the foreground and background.",
        "NSFaceIDUsageDescription":"Allows App to use Face ID for a simpler sign in.",
        "UIBackgroundModes":[
          "location",
          "fetch"
        ],
      }
    },
```

//Android Permissions

```
"android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "permissions":[
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
      ],

    },
```

Comment: Are you using expo build command or the new EAS workflow (e.g. eas build)?

Comment: Is the expo build command the same thing as running "Expo-Start" in my command line and running the app on my device? @SyedAffanHamdani

Comment: That means you are trying it on the Expo Go app. I would recommend updating the expo-cli to latest and test again.

Comment: @SyedAffanHamdani I am using the most up to date Expo-Cli. What's the difference between Expo-Build and Expo-Start?

Comment: expo build is used to build standalone apps. Like expo build:ios More info [here](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/)

Comment: Also may be [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12662) helps.

Comment: In theory, if it works on Android, would the format work on iOS as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239757/discussion-between-syed-affan-hamdani-and-mk-pierce).